# How to obtain the android_id of a device?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

In the licensing documentation the android developers mention an easy way to more or less securely identify an android device. They are using android.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID.

They say they query the system settings for this. But they don't explain this any further.

How do I obtain the android_id and do I need special permissions for doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all in the Javadoc, as linked to by this question you edited 30 minutes before this one! :)
[Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

The "Secure" part just means that apps can't write to it, only read.  I seem to recall that this device ID isn't always present; it's populated by the Market as required, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks I tried the code in the question and it didn't work but now I realized it was an error on my part and got it working.

Comment: I wanted to corroborate the part about the ID not always being present. When I tested on emulators we had issues with this. I don't remember if the ID was never present or was just occasionally missing, but I do remember that it was not always there on emulators

Answer (score 17):

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "SELECT value FROM secure WHERE name='android_id'"
```

The android id is changeable with a rooted phone...
Insert a android id with:

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "UPDATE secure SET value='IDHERE' WHERE name='android_id'"
```

Comment: This seems to no longer work on recent Androids. This worked for me instead: `adb shell settings get secure android_id`

Comment: The answer misses the fact that root permissions via `su` are required.

Comment: This no longer works! **settings.db is gone since Android 7**.