# Change Android Device Id

Tags: android, android-studio

I got device Id using following code

```
final String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I want to change this id by user any solution to it.
I know user must be rooted.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751475/150978 For changing just use sqlite `UPDATE` command. Not sure which Android versions are supported and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Values of `ANDROID_ID` are determined by your app signing key. It may be changed if user do a factory reset or change the signing key. User do not have to be rooted.